# Split PDF File into Individual Pages multi thread

Tags: java, multithreading, pdf, itext

I have a process of splitting PDFs with ITEXT 5.5.5. in Java, I work with threads to split a PDF in groups of 100k when I try to split large files.

```
String pdf ="D:\\189945\\PDF_GlobalElectronico_Opt.pdf";
RandomAccessFileOrArray fileRandom  = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(pdf);
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileRandom.createView(),null);
for(int i=0;listapaginas.size()-1>=i;i++){
    Document document = new Document(pdfReader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
    PdfCopy writer = null;
    writer = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream("D:\\global\\spliteados\\"+listapaginas.get(i).getNombrePDF()+".pdf"));
    writer.setFullCompression();
    document.open();
    PdfImportedPage page;
    for(int j=listapaginas.get(i).getPaginaInicio();listapaginas.get(i).getPaginaFin()>=j;j++){
        //System.out.println("sub  "+listapaginas.get(i).getPaginaInicio()+" -  "+listapaginas.get(i).getPaginaFin());
        page = writer.getImportedPage(pdfReader, j);

        try {
            writer.addPage(page);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ThreadPdfGenerador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (BadPdfFormatException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ThreadPdfGenerador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    document.close();
    writer.close();
}
pdfReader.close();
```

What I found out is:
If I split with one thread it takes the same time as with two or more.

I would like to know if the problem is because I'm reading the same PDF and it doesn't matter if I try to read it with one or more threads.

Example of threads
Thread 1 Pages 1 at 100000,

Thread 2 Pages 100001 at 200000,

Thread 3 Pages 200001 at 300000,

Thread 4 Pages 300001 at 400000,

Thread 5 Pages 400001 at 400000

Comment: Welcome to SO, when posting a question or answer could you format better the end is a little confusing, also don't say thank you before you have an answer.

Comment: It's not going to be easy: one needs a commercial license to investigate the source code of the IText. E.g. `writer.getImportedPage(pdfReader, j)` could be in a `syncrhonized`. If it's true then there's nothing `Threads` can do to speed it up.

Comment: @TamasRev *"one needs a commercial license to investigate the source code of the IText"* ???? iText is open source, you can get the source from github...